# Registering Custom checkin policy for VS2013

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, visual-studio-2013, checkin-policy

I installed Visual Studio 2013 and having problem with Custom Check in policies. I added new Key and Value to the registry:

> HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\12.0\TeamFoundation\SourceControl\Checkin
>   Policies\MyPolicyName

Basically I followed everything in this link: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb668980.aspx., but I still get error:

> Internal error in "My policy". Error loading the "MyPolicy" policy
>   (The policy assembly 'MyPolicy, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null' is not registered.). Installation instructions:
>   To install this policy, read InstallInstructions.txt.

Previously it was built in .NET 4.5 and worked fine with VS 2012. I though maybe building it in .NET 4.5.1 might fix the problem, but it didn't. What should I do to fix it? and where is the InstallInstructions.txt located?

UPDATE:

I am using TFS 2012 and SQL Server 2012. Visual Studio 2013 Premium (not preview).

Thanks for the help!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/21480219/736079

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally I figured what was wrong. I had two versions of Visual Studio installed. 2012 and 2013. Year ago I created a custom cheking policy using VS 2012 and I was trying to make it work with VS 2013. I tried rebuilding in VS 2013 and it didn't work. I tried rebuilding it in a machine that only has VS 2013 and figured that it was still referencing to VS 2012 libraries. So I basically removed all references added VS2013 libraries. That solved the issue.

[here at msdn forum](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/27139055-c9c9-4003-9d7a-0ac737832422/how-to-register-custom-checkin-policy-for-visual-studio-2013?forum=tfsgeneral).

Comment: Just adding my blog link here for future reference, should people run into similar issues: http://blog.jessehouwing.nl/2014/01/creating-custom-check-in-policy-pack.html